# Getting KeyError in iterating rows for a Chi-sqaure test

Tags: python, pandas

I am running a chi-square test for subgroups, so when the file is read I want to look at specific groups. It works fine but I have many subgroups and a for loop will be the ideal solution to do that but with my current code it only runs the test for the first subgroup and it crashes.

```
group = [
 
    
    ['HESF',
    'HESM'],
    ['HCSF',
    'HCSM']
]

for i in group: 
   
    table = table.loc[table['condition'].isin(i)]
    table= table.set_index('condition')

    def chisq_and_posthoc_corrected(table):

        """Receives a dataframe and performs chi2 test and then post hoc.
        Prints the p-values and corrected p-values (after FDR correction)"""
        # start by running chi2 test on the matrix
        chi2, p, dof, ex = chi2_contingency( table, correction=True)
        print(f"Chi2 result of the contingency table: {chi2}, p-value: {p}, dof: {dof}")
        
        # post-hoc
        all_combinations = list(combinations(table.index, 2))  # gathering all combinations for post-hoc chi2
        p_vals = []
        print("Significance results:")
        for comb in all_combinations:
            new_df = table[(table.index == comb[0]) | (table.index == comb[1])]
            chi2, p, dof, ex = chi2_contingency(new_df, correction=True)
            p_vals.append(p)
            # print(f"For {comb}: {p}")  # uncorrected

        # checking significance
        # correction for multiple testing
        reject_list, corrected_p_vals = multipletests(p_vals, method='fdr_bh')[:2]
        for p_val, corr_p_val, reject, comb in zip(p_vals, corrected_p_vals, reject_list, all_combinations):
            print(f"{comb}: p_value: {p_val:5f}; corrected: {corr_p_val:5f} ({get_asterisks_for_pval(p_val)}) reject: {reject}")
            
    chisq_and_posthoc_corrected(table)
```

the error I am getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/miniconda3/envs/ucdv1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 2646, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(key)
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 111, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 138, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1618, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1626, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 'condition'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "chi-square.py", line 24, in <module>
    table = table.loc[table['condition'].isin(i)]
  File "/opt/miniconda3/envs/ucdv1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2800, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
  File "/opt/miniconda3/envs/ucdv1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 2648, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 111, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 138, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1618, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1626, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 'condition'
```

the dataframe

```
  condition  correct  incorrect  timeout  skip  text
0      HESF        3          3        0     9     5
1       HPS        7          4        1     4     4
2      HCSF        5          0        1     8     6
3      HESM        7          3        1     7     2
4      HCSM        9          3        1     6     1
```

Comment: Can you show the `pd.DataFrame` table?

Comment: I added the dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because in the first pass on the for loop you are changing the **table** and setting 'condition' as the index and in the second pass this column doesn't exist anymore, I think what you want is to make a copy of the dataframe:

```
group = [
 
    
    ['HESF',
    'HESM'],
    ['HCSF',
    'HCSM']
]

for i in group: 
   
    table_copy = table.loc[table['condition'].isin(i)].copy()
    table_copy = table_copy.set_index('condition')

    def chisq_and_posthoc_corrected(table):

        """Receives a dataframe and performs chi2 test and then post hoc.
        Prints the p-values and corrected p-values (after FDR correction)"""
        # start by running chi2 test on the matrix
        chi2, p, dof, ex = chi2_contingency( table, correction=True)
        print(f"Chi2 result of the contingency table: {chi2}, p-value: {p}, dof: {dof}")
        
        # post-hoc
        all_combinations = list(combinations(table.index, 2))  # gathering all combinations for post-hoc chi2
        p_vals = []
        print("Significance results:")
        for comb in all_combinations:
            new_df = table[(table.index == comb[0]) | (table.index == comb[1])]
            chi2, p, dof, ex = chi2_contingency(new_df, correction=True)
            p_vals.append(p)
            # print(f"For {comb}: {p}")  # uncorrected

        # checking significance
        # correction for multiple testing
        reject_list, corrected_p_vals = multipletests(p_vals, method='fdr_bh')[:2]
        for p_val, corr_p_val, reject, comb in zip(p_vals, corrected_p_vals, reject_list, all_combinations):
            print(f"{comb}: p_value: {p_val:5f}; corrected: {corr_p_val:5f} ({get_asterisks_for_pval(p_val)}) reject: {reject}")
            
    chisq_and_posthoc_corrected(table_copy)
```